# hidden (?) files

Tags: basic4android

I'm writing an app that includes a folder/file explorer.  That part is working.  However,  another app (Astro File Manager) has the ability to backup all of the installed apps to a backup location on the SD card.  I cannot find or see the folder(s) where installed apps are stored.  Supposedly it is in "/data/apps".  My phone is NOT rooted and Astro works fine.  Does anyone know what the trick is to seeing these folders/files?  Is it possible to do this in B4A? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android doesn't allow you to access other programs files. Astro probably uses the backup API that allows you to backup other programs. However the backup API doesn't give you access to the files.

Comment: That makes sense Erel, because in Astro's "explorer" they do not display those directories either.  I will look up details of the backup API.  Thanks!!